# Prawn html formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf-generation, prawn, prawnto

I have some simple lists and bold/italic text to format with prawn. How do I get prawn to pay attention to the html tags instead of just displaying them explicitly.

If prawn can't do this, what are my other options?

Comment: which version of Prawn do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline formatting has been completely re-instated in the development version of Prawn.

You can use the code off of the stable branch (0.9.x) for stability, or track master, where we just merged inline styling support for tables.  See notes at:

http://wiki.github.com/sandal/prawn/changelog-dev

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Prawn changelog](http://wiki.github.com/sandal/prawn/changelog):

> We had planned to write up the
>   necessary steps for getting
>   prawn-format back into the fold, but
>   instead, we are working on a
>   replacement that will be supported in
>   core. More details to come soon.

You might want to create an issue on their github page to find out the roadmap for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

There was http://github.com/sandal/prawn-format for this, but now it is out of date and not supported.

`As of Prawn 0.7, prawn-format is completely unsupported, and will not work with versions of Prawn 0.7+. Feel free to fork and fix, of course.`

Comment: Ya I found that, but it seems to me that this would be an issue that many people would use so there would be more options.