# Rails 3 and Prawn - HTML formatting doesn't work?

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, prawn

I opened Prawn's [manual](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/manual.pdf) page and try to use HTML formatting in PDF document. Specifically,

```
pdf.table([["Just <font size='18'>some</font> <b><i>inline</i></b>", "", ""],
          ["<color rgb='FF00FF'>styles</color> being applied here", "", ""]],
          :cell_style => { :inline_format => true }, :cell_style => {:borders => []})
```

The problem is, that the HTML tags are displayd as the HTML tags, have anyone the same problem? By the documentation the HTML tags should display a HTML property, but in fact are displayed only HTML tags.

Have anyone a tip how to fix it?

I use the Prawn in the version

```
* prawn (0.12.0)
* prawnto (0.0.4)
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like this is supposed anymore ( [Prawn html formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692862/prawn-html-formatting) ) -- if you want to use HTML to make your PDF's you can use PDFKit ( https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit ) which also supports CSS.

Answer (score 2):

I have used prawn to create the pdf and if u take my opinion u dont need to use the prawnto gem with prawn in rails 3.
i have just created a blog on this.check this out i have explained it from scratch on how to use prawn with the sample invoice.
http://www.idyllic-software.com/blog/creating-pdf-using-prawn-in-ruby-on-rails/

thanks

aniket

Comment: This has now moved to http://www.idyllic-software.com/blog/creating-pdf-using-prawn-in-ruby-on-rails/